# Audio middleware unity package missing assembly references

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, .net-assembly, wwise

I want to use AudioKinetic WWise middleware to implement audio to a mobile game I'm working at the moment but I'm experiencing trouble assembly references thus I'm not able to code the audio scripts I need for the game.

**Setup**

- Unity 2021.3.22f1
- Visual Studio Community 2019
- Unity development with Unity VS workload
- Wwise 2022.1.5.8242
- Wwise Unity integration 2022.1.5.8242.2798

**Packages**

- Visual Studio Editor 2.0.18
- Firebase
- Doozy UI

**Attemps to sort out the issue**

- Install the work environment from scratch
- Pull repo from scratch
- Add missing reference to the main project assembly definition as described here: [Unity - Manual: Assembly definition files](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.3/Documentation/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html)
- Remove all `.csproj` `.sln` files from the root folder
- Check `Building settings` platform is **Android**
- Integrate Wwise to another project -> works fine!
- Integrate a different audio middleware **FMOD Studio** -> didn't work either
- Regenerate files from Preferences -> External tools regenerate project files
- Check that Visual Studio is indeed my `External script editor`
- Keep a clean console from error non-related to this issues (console has been clean always)
- Code something with Unity MonoBehaviour API -> autocomplete works fine, no compilation errors
- Delete `manifest.json`

**Console Output**

`Error    CS0234    The type or namespace name 'Event' does not exist in the namespace 'AK.Wwise' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    _ai-space-shooter    C:\Unity Projects\NFTCo\ai-space-shooter\Assets\_ai-space-shooter\Audio\PlayAudioEvent.cs    7    Active`

What bothers me is that the issue happens with this specific project and I've not been able to nail down what is preventing me from using any middleware API. My last resort is to implement audio logic with Unity native audio API because I'd need to code a lot and my result is potentially more error prone than relying on APIs that having been thouroughly tested. If you are an audio person, you know how painful not being able to work with an audio middleware can be.

Does anyone have previous experience with the same issue?

Comment: You dont mention what exactly is failing and what messages you get

Comment: @BugFinder thanks for pointing that out. It's already been added to the question